# "If-Modified-Since" Header?

Tags: http-headers, if-modified-since

I wanted to know how to check the server response of "**If-Modified-Since**" header sent by my browser.
I am not sure how do I achieve it.
Any help would be a great deal to me, Thanks.

Comment: We cannot help if you are not more specific, for example, what technology and/or software are you using.

Comment: html and php is all that I am using !!

Comment: Why the "!!" - are we supposed to read your mind??? (deliberate triple-? to counter the double-!) Anyway, the Q makes no apparent sense. The browser says "send data unless you have something newer than xx:xx:xx". So the server sends something or not - it is YOUR script's decision what to tell the browser, i.e. send something or send nothing and send the HTTP status code for "not modified" only. What are we to advice? There is nothing to "check". **YOU** are the one generating the response!

Answer (score 0):

Check the HTTP response code (e.g., using `curl`). If the resource is not modified you get a `304` response, else, in the non-error case, a `200`.